# Photoshop: Resize/Scale proportionally (percentages) every text (different layers) in a file

Tags: text, automation, scripting, resize, photoshop

Could anyone gimme some help on how to create a script that would resize all my texts in a file?

I create a lot of menus for restaurants etc, sometimes I come to the conclusion it would be better if every text were 15% smaller, for e.g., but I have hundreds of different layers, with different hierarchies (categories name, products, options, etc). Free transform would solve but then every text would move - and my main reason for finding how to proportionally resize everything together is to keep every element exactly where they are.
I don't have any special requirements concerning text boxes nor anything like that, I'd just like to resize fonts and keep everything in place.

Comment: What have you tried, what didn't work? It should be quite straightforward: you iterate through layers, check their `kind`, if the kind is text, you do `layer.resize()`

Comment: Don't use a hammer to drive a screw. Use a software made to lay out text, like InDesign. Style sheets will do wonders for this kind of adjustments